# Having difficulty with the start argument for ts( ). Losing date formatting

Tags: r, date

First, new to programming.

I built a table with 3 columns and I want to evaluate based on time series, so I'm playing around with the ts() function. The first column of my table is DATE as.date in the format "yyyy-mm-dd". I have one observation per variable per day. I've apply ts() to the table and tried start=1 (first observation?) and checked head(df) and the DATE column is sending back loose sequence of numbers that I can't identify (12591, 12592, 12593, 12594, 12597, 12598).

Could it be that the as.date is messing things up?

The line I use is:

```
ts(dy2, start=1, frequency= 1)
```

I've also been playing with the deltat argument. In the help file it suggests 1/12 for monthly data. Naturally, I tried 1/365 (for daily data), but have yet to be successful.

Comment: Please include some sample data (possibly the `head()` of the data.frame you created) to create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: `ts` is not suitable for daily series. Use the zoo and xts packages instead.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by  G. Grothendieck you can use the `zoo` package. Try this:

```
require(zoo)
dates <- as.Date(dy2[,1], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
x1 <- zoo(dy2[,2], dates)
plot(x2)
x2 <- zoo(dy2[,3], dates)
plot(x1)
```

If this does not work, please provide further details about your data as requested by MrFlick. For example, print the output of `dput(dy2)` or at least `head(dy2)`.